# trim string to a specific character

Tags: android, string, trim

I want to trim a specific String till a specific character. So the String: `com.icecoldapps.screenshoteasy` for example shall be the String `screenshoteasy`. But larger Strings like `com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts` shall also be trimed to `contacts`.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String yourString = "com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts";
String[] sArr = yourString.split("\\.");
String output = sArr[sArr.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split method to return a array with the string split into parts on a delimiter.

```
String whole = "com.icecoldapps.screenshoteasy"
String[] parts = whole.split('.');
```

So parts would be `["com" , "icecoldapps", "screenshoteasy"]`

You can also split using more complicated strings of characters. Might be worth looking at Regular Expressions and [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for that.